# Solving this DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an ODE as follows-

$i\frac{dU}{dz} = -\frac{1}{2}\beta\omega^2U$

where $U = U(z,\omega)$

Separating the variables, I got-

$\frac{dU}{U} = -\frac{\beta\omega^2dz}{2i}$

Integrating, I get-

$ln(U) = \frac{i\beta\omega^2z}{2}$

and hence,

$U = e^{\frac{i\beta\omega^2z}{2}} + C$.

However, the book says the solution is-

$U(z,\omega) = U(0,\omega)e^{\frac{i\beta\omega^2z}{2}}$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where's the constant of integration?

Comment: You forgot to add a constant after integration.

Comment: You have a PDE, not ODE --- the $\omega$ in $U(z,\omega)$ is a variable that does not relate to $z$.

Comment: Thanks. I added the constant now. How do  I get the equation to go the form I need?

Comment: The constant of integration pops out when you actually do the integration, not at the very last moment. That means that it enters into the formula for $U$ *inside the exponential*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one integrates the separated equation

$\dfrac{dU}{U} = -\dfrac{\beta \omega^2 dz}{2i} \tag 1$

'twixt $0$ and $z$, one obtains

$\ln U(z,\omega) - \ln U(0, \omega)$
$= \displaystyle \int_0^z \dfrac{dU}{U} = -\int_0^z \dfrac{\beta \omega^2 ds}{2i} = i\dfrac{\beta \omega^2}{2} \int_0^z ds = i\dfrac{\beta \omega^2 z}{2} , \tag 2$

that is,

$\ln \left( \dfrac{U(z, \omega)}{U(0, \omega)} \right ) = i\dfrac{\beta \omega^2}{2} z, \tag 3$

whence

$\dfrac{U(z, \omega)}{U(0, \omega)} = \exp \left (i\dfrac{\beta \omega^2 z}{2} \right), \tag 4$

or

$U(z, \omega) = U(0, \omega) \exp \left ( i\dfrac{\beta \omega^2 z}{2} \right ), \tag 5$

in accord with "the book".

*What am I doing wrong?*  The limits of the definite integral

$\displaystyle \int_0^z \dfrac{dU}{U} \tag 6$

we're apparently neglected in our OP Paddy's calculations.

Comment: Thanks! Also, I think there is an extra dz in equation 2 on the right side of dU/U integral.

Comment: @Paddy:  Thank you for the "acceptance", and for noticing my typo.  Fixed!  ***Cheers!***

Comment: +1 Robert I just changed the $dz$ into $ ds$ in the integral ..

Comment: @Aryadeva:  OK, thanks.  Must have missed that one!  ***Cheers!***